# CSV file error while trying to access it

Tags: python, csv

scenario: 
I'm trying to extract tweets from twitter, which is working fine,
next I'm trying to merge 10 files into 1(say file = QW).

```
    for line in file: 
      my_row = [line]
      filename = line.rstrip()+"_tweets"+".csv"
      if(os.path.exists(filename)):
        f = open(filename, "rt")
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for line in enumerate(reader):
            my_row.append(line) 
        writer.writerow(my_row) 
    else:
        print(""+filename+ " doesnt exist")
```

[my csv file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUmWx.png)
and then I will process that one file

problem: I want to read specific column of that CSV(QW) file

I tried row[0]

```
    for row in input_file:
    name_list = [] ;score = 0;
    name_list.append(row[0])
    print(name_list)
    for a in row:
        if a.find(skill_input) > 0 :
            score = score+1;


    name_list.append(score)
    print(name_list)
    writer.writerow([name_list])
```

and that point I get an error
[my csv file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUmWx.png)
       name_list.append(row[0])
       IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The snippet of code you have provided is likely not enough to diagnose the problem - can you provide some more of your code?

Comment: Also add examples of your data.

Comment: And what does `print row` show?

Comment: this looks like no data is being added at all

Comment: updated the question @asongtoruin

Comment: @running.t 
it prints the entire row from csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for line in open("csvfile.csv"):
    csv_row = line.split(your_delimiter) #returns a list ["1","50","60"]
    if not csv_row[k]:
        continue
    name_list.append(csv_row[k]) # Or csv_row[k] for specific kth column
```

Comment: csv_row = row.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: csv_row = row.split('\t')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

same error yet

Comment: Try opening the file also the way it's in my answer

Comment: can you tell me the way to skip blank lines too?

Comment: for row in open("merge1.csv"):
 
  if not row.strip(): 
   continue
   
  name_list = [] ;score = 0;
  csv_row = row.split('\t') 
  name_list.append(csv_row[0])['"']
['"', 0]

Comment: for a in row:
             if a.find(skill_input) > 0 :
         score = score+1;

Comment: this code used to work earlier, n now it doesn't return any score. any idea why?

Comment: Erm.. I think I'll need some more code to figure that out and I think you should ask it in another question as well if possible..

Comment: cant ask another question for next 3 days. :(